# Linker error while building Gstreamer iOS Tutorial project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, gstreamer

I downloaded and installed Gstreamer iOS library from [their site](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+iOS+development). I copied the tutorial to my own folder and tried to build the project in Xcode. I got the following linker error.

I'm geting no clues about this. The Gstreamer.framework is linked against all targets.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      __nl_find_msg in GStreamer(libintl_a_armv7_-dcigettext.o)
     (maybe you meant: _g_iconv_open)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      __nl_find_msg in GStreamer(libintl_a_armv7_-dcigettext.o)
     (maybe you meant: _iconv_canonicalize, _g_iconv_close , _g_convert_with_iconv , _g_iconv , _g_iconv_open )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What OBVIOUS thing am I missing here?

### SOLUTION

---

No issues with the framework. I just had to add libiconv.dylib in Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries. No linker errors after that!

Comment: Whole framework is missing. Framework is not added correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**FOUND IT!!!**

No issues with the framework. I just had to add **libiconv.dylib** in Build Phases -> Link binary with libraries. No linker errors after that!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is drag the library project into your project. Then in your project settings, goto `Build Phases` and under `Target Dependencies` add the library project as dependency. Then under `Link Binary With Libraries` (still in Build Phases), add the library's product (a .a file). Then rebuild.

In recent versions of Xcode, you don't even need to add it as a target dependency. It automatically detects dependencies between projects in the same workspace. You just need to add the .a file under `Link Binary With Libraries`.

Comment: but there is no "library project". From the installer page - **The SDK library is installed to ~/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk. Inside this directory there is the GStreamer.framework that contains the libs, headers and resources.**

Comment: in that case, just add GStreamer.framework under 'Link Binary With Libraries'.

Comment: Gstreamer.framework was already there...but it was in "red". I still added gstreamer.framework from the iPhone.sdk path. Still the same result. I have applied the framework for all targets

Answer (score 0):

Update:

We found another developer who has hit the same issues and has made available modified tutorials to work around the overlay.h missing and a couple of other issues, if you are interested check this out: 
https://github.com/braincorp/gstreamer_ios_tutorial